# Coursera Module 7 Week 3: R unite function does not work after a separate function on same data

Tags: r

The instructor showed the unite function without discussing what she added before writing the unite function.  However, I looked at the video screen, saw what she had inputted, and added it in, but it still didn't work.  Unfortunately no other student on coursera knows the answer either- crickets.

This worked successfully:
separate(employee, name,into=c('first_name','last_name'), sep=' ')

A unite function performed right after that results in an error, no such column, even though its exactly what she had on the screen:

unite(employee,"name", first_name, last_name, sep=' ')

When I print(employee), it refers to the original column that was not separated so of course this action is futile.

How do i unite after separate of the same data?

I appreciate you gurus!

Comment: Your post should contain code that makes your issue reproducible so we don't need to guess at what the problem is.  However, it seems like you didn't assign the result, i.e you should do `employee <- separate(employee, name,into=c('first_name','last_name'), sep=' ')`.